# Multiple connections to Plex dlna port 32469

Tags: raspberry-pi, netstat, dlna, tcpdump, plex

Sorry if this is not in the correct forum.

I have Plex server installed on a Raspberry PI running Raspbian with Open Media Vault. Everything works well.

The only issue I have is that I get lots of connections from my partners Android phone trying to connect to the Pi using the DLNA port 32469.

tcp      836      0 192.168.1.200:32469     192.168.1.67:36394      ESTABLISHED

tcp      836      0 192.168.1.200:32469     192.168.1.67:36399      ESTABLISHED

tcp      836      0 192.168.1.200:32469     192.168.1.67:36399      ESTABLISHED

02:07:57.091716 IP android-d237337ff7efeef8.home.39475 > home-pi.home.32469: Flags [P.], seq 1:837, ack 1, win 1369, options [nop,nop,TS val 8979608 ecr 46423], length 836

02:07:57.091890 IP home-pi.home.32469 > android-d237337ff7efeef8.home.39475: Flags [.], ack 837, win 240, options [nop,nop,TS val 46424 ecr 8979608], length 0

02:07:57.094783 IP android-d237337ff7efeef8.home.39476 > home-pi.home.32469: Flags [.], ack 1, win 1369, options [nop,nop,TS val 8979609 ecr 46424], length 0

TCPDump and Nethogs shows multiple connections every second. Is this a setting within Android to stop it automatically trying to connect to the Pi? My understand was that you specifically request the Android handset to connect to a DLNA device when using an app such as YouTube.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what kind of android you're using but if it's a Samsung, install noroot firewall and see if the packets are coming from "nearby service"

I ended up here from that side of things, trying to figure out why that service was regularly trying to access my NAS (which is also a plex server) on that port

Even though I have that feature turned off, it's still trolling my network.  The only way I know of to completely shut it off is to uninstall it (the nuclear option) or turn off its network access through noroot firewall